# How to convert row data into a single column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table as follows with 3 columns

```
First_Name Last_Name ID
AAA        ZZZ        3   
BBB        YYY        1   
CCC        XXX        2
```

I want the outout based on the sorting order of ID value into a single row 
The output should look like this

```
BBB YYY CCC XXX AAA ZZZ
```

Please help me out in getting the required output.

regards
sivakiran B

Comment: Do you want this as a single column or as six? what Oracle version are you using?

Comment: What about PIVOT / UNPIVOT?  http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Comment: Hi Mureinik, I want this as six columns

Comment: Hi Leptonator, I have gone through PIVOT, but in all the forums it has explained as using with aggregate functions. So i didn;t understand that much about that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(first_name||' '||last_name, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS namelist
  FROM your_table;
```